# Validity of Weibull distribution

Tags: distributions, modeling, weibull-distribution

I have come across validation engineers picking the Weibull distribution as a way to generate test stimulus. When they do this, they seem to chose the parameterisation without reference to any particular 'real-world' constraints of the scenario.

Superficially, it seems that their intent would be clearer if they were using a more explicit distribution shape (exponential, normal, binned-to-fit-the-protocol) rather than having this abstracted by the shape parameter (or being explicitly fit to serve a well defined goal).

It seems that the Weibull distribution is useful when you have a complex dataset and need a generalised distribution which is not linked to the underlying process - and this does not seem to be the case - unless the requirement is to (for example) show consistent performance across a range of parameterised datasets. This might be valuable to analyse a network in the presence of predominantly short packets and check that is it working as well as for predominantly long packets.

If Weibull is not a good distribution to use without reference to a real dataset, is there a reason for it seeming to be popular?

To try and clarify, assuming that there is no real dataset which we're trying to replicate, is there any particular reason to prefer or avoid Weibull? Should I, as a non-expert reviewer, worry that this choice has hidden the actual choice behind a parameter (or even deferred that choice)? I think the alternative would be that this is a common or standard approach to generating arbitrary synthetic data.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to be more precise. You seem to be saying, that some people use simulated data from Weibull distribution, to test some things, and ask if this is valid. This is extremely vague. It can be, or cannot be, valid depending on particular case.

Comment: @Tim, I think I'm asking if this would be a common solution to the 'I need some synthetic data', or more unusual. Not so much if it is inapropriate, because that will be subjective.

Comment: If you just need "some" data, it can be Weibull, normal, uniform, you can choose anything you want. When writing unit tests in programming, we often [mock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) some things, i.e. create objects that meed *minimal formal conditions* to be considered as "similar", same applies to producing fake data.

Comment: Also, note that, in contrast to simple classic distributions, Weibull is quite convenient due to its flexible nature. [See, for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution), the effect of changing $k$ value. I.e., it can model left-skewed, right-skewed, symmetric data

Comment: Could you explain what is "more explicit" about a Normal distribution compared to a Weibull distribution?

Comment: @whuber Maybe 'less parameterised' would be more precise.

Comment: They both have exactly two parameters. How is one "less parameterized" than the other?

Comment: Thank you--that does clear up your meaning.  You're wrong, though, because both the Normal and Weibull families are two-parameter families.  And, whatever "binned-to-fit-the protocol" might mean, it sounds like it involves many parameters (at least one for each bin cutpoint).

Comment: The Weibull distribution is one of the limiting distributions for extreme values such as the minimum of an i.i.d. sample.

Comment: I have used Weibull distributions when those are the best functions that fit data, e.g., https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5522/99274. The Weibull result may be relevant as one interpretation of the Weibull distribution relates to [diffusion of innovation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_of_innovations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absent detailed information, the Weibull family has several advantages as a model of failure times:

- It includes the (constant-hazard) [exponential distribution as a
  special
  case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution#Standard_parameterization)
  with other parameter values allowing for hazards that either rise or
  fall over time.
- The Weibull family is the only family whose nature is maintained
     under both [proportional hazards and accelerated failure
     time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerated_failure_time_model#Distributions_used_in_AFT_models)
     modeling.
- Weibull-distributed failure times are related to the [minimum
     extreme-value
     distribution](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/apr/section1/apr163.htm).
     The minimum extreme-value distribution applies for example to a
     series of *n* components in series, for which the entire system
     fails once the first component fails. The distribution of the
     logarithm of Weibull failure times is a minimum extreme-value
     distribution with location and scale determined by the shape and
     scale parameters of the Weibull.
- The [Weibull
     plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution#Weibull_plot)
     is a simple and convenient way to display failure-time data and to test whether that distribution adequately models the data.

So there are several reasons to use the Weibull distribution for failure times. One of its few major drawbacks is that it does not allow for non-monotonic hazards as a function of time.